# How to perform further grouping and lookups in .SD for a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the following sample hflights data, I would like to find out the max and min ArrDelays and the corresponding UniqueCarrier and the Dest for each Origin airport and Month. I got it to work but i feel it could be made simpler.

For each .SD, I can find the min(ArrDelay) and Max(ArrDelay)  but I also need the Airline and Dest corresponding to the Min and Max ArrDelay. Is there a way to perform that lookup ?

```
library(data.table)
library(hflights)

DT <- as.data.table(hflights)

setkey(DT, Origin, Month)


DT[, 
 c(head(.SD[,  .(MaxArrDelay=max(ArrDelay, na.rm = TRUE), Dest) , by=UniqueCarrier][order(-MaxArrDelay)], 1),
   head(.SD[,  .(MinArrDelay=min(ArrDelay, na.rm = TRUE), Dest) , by=UniqueCarrier][order(MinArrDelay)], 1) )
, by=.(Origin, Month) ]

# Test the output for a single record... 
DT[ .("HOU", 1), .(max(na.omit(ArrDelay)), min(na.omit(ArrDelay)))]
```

Comment: Have you tried `which.min`, `which.max`

Comment: What is your desired output? I would suggest reducing your problem to something smaller. Also, probably @akrun already answered this.

Comment: Thank you @akrun for pointing me to `which.min` and `which.max`. those are the functions to use.  I realized my example code produces incorrect Dest due to recycling.

Comment: Have you checked with the code I showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 res1 <- DT[, {min1 <- which.min(ArrDelay)
               max1 <- which.max(ArrDelay)
               list(DestMin=Dest[min1],
               ArrDelayMin=ArrDelay[min1],
               MinUniqueCarrier= UniqueCarrier[min1],
               DestMax= Dest[max1],
               ArrDelayMax= ArrDelay[max1], 
               MaxUniqueCarrier=UniqueCarrier[max1] )}, 
                                 by = .(Origin, Month)]
```

Or this can be made compact by

```
 nm1 <- c('Dest', 'ArrDelay', 'UniqueCarrier')   
 res2 <- DT[, c(.SD[which.min(ArrDelay)], .SD[which.max(ArrDelay)]) , 
                   by = .(Origin, Month), .SDcols= nm1]
 setnames(res2, 3:ncol(res2), paste0(nm1, rep(c('Min', 'Max'),each=length(nm1))))

 all.equal(res1, res2, check.attributes=FALSE)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
grh <- group_by(hflights, Origin, Month)
Min <- grh %>% 
         slice(which.min(ArrDelay)) %>% 
         select(Dest, ArrDelay, UniqueCarrier) %>%
         setNames(., c(names(.)[1:2], paste0(names(.)[3:5], 'Min')))
Max <- grh %>% 
         slice(which.max(ArrDelay)) %>% 
         select(Dest, ArrDelay, UniqueCarrier) %>%
         setNames(., c(names(.)[1:2], paste0(names(.)[3:5], 'Max')))
bind_cols(Min, Max[-(1:2)])
```