# How to perform further grouping and lookups on aggregated values in .SD for a data.table -

Tags: r, data.table

This is related to the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300030/how-to-perform-further-grouping-and-lookups-in-sd-for-a-data-table) on grouping/lookups on data.table but with additional output.

I am trying to perform a grouping on the subset .SD and select values from the each subset. For example, in the flights dataset, i would like to find out : For each airport and month, which UniqueCarrier and Destination has the worst avg ArrDelay. So there are essentially 2 levels of aggregation.

I have the working solution as follows.. But it would be good to understand if there are any better solutions.

```
library(data.table)
library(hflights)

DT <- as.data.table(hflights)

setkey(DT, Origin, Month)

#The solution code...
DT[, {
 t1 <- .SD[, .(mean(na.omit(ArrDelay))) , by=UniqueCarrier];
 max1 <- which.max(t1$V1);
 t2 <- .SD[, .(mean(na.omit(ArrDelay))) , by=Dest];
 max2 <- which.max(t2$V1);
 list( MaxAvgDelayForCarrier = t1$UniqueCarrier[max1], MaxAvgDelayByCarrier = t1$V1[max1],  MaxAvgDelayByDest= t2$Dest[max2], MaxAvgDelayForDest= t2$V1[max2] )
},  by = .(Origin, Month)]

# Checking for correctness
head(DT[ .("HOU", 1), .(MaxAvgDelayByCarrier=mean(na.omit(ArrDelay))), by=UniqueCarrier][order(-MaxAvgDelayByCarrier)],1)
head(DT[ .("IAH", 2), .(MaxAvgDelayForDest=mean(na.omit(ArrDelay))), by=Dest][order(-MaxAvgDelayForDest)],1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is fine, but I would write it this way:

```
DT[,c(

  .SD[, 
    .(CMaxVal = mean(na.omit(ArrDelay))),
  by=.(CMax = UniqueCarrier)][which.max(CMaxVal)],

  .SD[, 
    .(DMaxVal = mean(na.omit(ArrDelay))),
  by=.(DMax = Dest)][which.max(DMaxVal)]

),by=key(DT)]
```

which gives

```
    Origin Month CMax   CMaxVal DMax  DMaxVal
 1:    HOU     1   F9 13.725806  PHL 20.12500
 2:    HOU     2   B6 17.822222  ECP 20.17308
 3:    HOU     3   EV 23.088889  PHL 46.06452
 4:    HOU     4   EV 27.847826  PHL 67.93333
 5:    HOU     5   EV 25.436620  PHL 75.61290
 6:    HOU     6   EV 16.930233  EWR 34.87755
 7:    HOU     7   B6 20.016129  CHS 21.54839
 8:    HOU     8   B6 30.163636  JFK 30.16364
 9:    HOU     9   DL 18.625000  EWR 14.32143
10:    HOU    10   DL 17.803279  PHL 22.51613
11:    HOU    11   F9  3.000000  EWR 18.46429
12:    HOU    12   MQ 13.554502  EWR 28.17857
13:    IAH     1   EV 15.682353  HNL 21.52632
14:    IAH     2   MQ 19.946809  BPT 29.00000
15:    IAH     3   AS 15.354839  SFO 27.43590
16:    IAH     4   MQ 16.263441  SEA 22.48515
17:    IAH     5   MQ 25.179104  DAY 25.96154
18:    IAH     6   UA 24.453125  ANC 34.06667
19:    IAH     7   OO 15.117419  DSM 32.39286
20:    IAH     8   UA 17.297561  ANC 37.96552
21:    IAH     9   UA 11.620000  SJU 16.76923
22:    IAH    10   UA 11.601266  CID 16.88462
23:    IAH    11   MQ  8.445545  CID 18.04167
24:    IAH    12   XE 11.376852  HOB 25.95556
    Origin Month CMax   CMaxVal DMax  DMaxVal
```

There's no need to store so many intermediate objects (`t1`, `max1`, etc.).

---

The approach above requires manually coding for each grouping variable. You could instead do...

```
DT[,do.call(c,lapply(c("UniqueCarrier","Dest"),
  function(colname) setNames(
    .SD[,mean(na.omit(ArrDelay)),by=c(colname)][which.max(V1)],
    paste0(c("max_","maxval_"),colname)
  )
)),by=key(DT)]
```